# Storage of configuration strings in asp.net core apps

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In a .NET Framework app, you can use `aspnet_regiis` to encrypt portions of the web.config including the connection strings.

Now that the connection strings in an asp.net core application are stored in `appsettings.json`, how do you encrypt those connection strings in a production environment?

I see several other similar questions, but they all seem to be related to folks asking about using User Secrets, which I understand cannot be used in production.

Comment: Even if your connection strings are stored in plaintext in `appsettings.json`, that file should not be accessible by your users, no?

Comment: Check docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows , there are a few others as well that you should take some time and review. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#security

Comment: @Nkosi The first link deals with development environments which I specifically said I was not talking about.   The second one seems to only refer to using Azure Key Vault.

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe correct.   But there is heartburn from our security folks that they are in plaintext.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code if you encrypt it, you'll have to store the encryption key somewhere, yes? I fail to see how this is any more secure than just keeping your appsettings.json private.

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe unfortunately, not me pushing to encrypt them.   It is the security team.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to push back and point out that it isn't any more secure to encrypt those files.

Comment: Security team reads things and doesn't seem to take realistic feedback from my development team.

Comment: You got any solution for this ?